# Convert async calls to sync?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, asynchronous, publish-subscribe

I got problems to handle async calls.

For example I want to load some modules dynamically with requirejs. 
Currently I use the subscriber-publisher pattern. Unfortunately this makes my code
in some situation really confusing...:

*imagine there is a working event system in the object*

```
var loader = {
    load: function(modules) {
        // do a async requirejs call
        require(modules, function(){
            // map arguments to normal array
            var modules = [].slice().call(arguments);
            // fire loaded event, pass modules
            this.trigger('loaded', modules);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};


var parent = {
    // do some initialization work
    initialize: function() {
        // execute the second initialization when our modules have finished loading async
        loader.on('loaded', this.secondInitialize, this);
        // require the given modules in the array
        loader.load(['one', 'two', 'three']);
    },

    secondInitialize: function(modules) {
        var three = new modules[2]();
        // do something with the 'three' module
    }

};
```

As you see this is really confusing.

**Are there any other design patterns which allow handsome handling of async calls?**

Comment: This is an unfortunate side-effect of the way asynchronous works in Javascript. There is no catch-all solution.

Comment: @usr maybe not a catch-all but an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [jQuery Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). (Even without jq, most libraries have an implementation of javascript promises)

With it you can do something like this:

```
var loadingOne = getLibOne(); //returns a jquery deferred promise
var loadingTwo = getLibTwo(); //returns another one

var loadingAllLibraries = $.when(loadingOne, loadingTwo);
loadingAllLibraries.done(function(lib1, lib2) {
  //... stuff
});
```

Not exactly your scenario but you get the idea. It becomes relatively easy to compose asynchronous atoms.

Comment: @kyogron - The best way to do that is to check out the link above and to start playing with it. It's scary looking but really not very complex. The more generalized idea you can look up by googling "javascript promises"

Comment: Sounds good will check out how I could implement this best in my project :)

Comment: @kyogron - by the way, a similar feature that was introduced with one of the later jQuerys is callbacks http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/ which allows you to quickly create publish/subscribe queues

Comment: Now it is normalized as Promise in Javascript  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise